# Definition of scheme-theoretic multiplicity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

In Gathmann's notes on algebraic geometry (https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002.pdf), he remarks in Lemma 6.1.4. (page 93) that the length of a zero-dimensional projective subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n$ can be viewed as the number of points in $X$ counted with "scheme-theoretic multiplicity" (he also defines it as follows: $X$ is affine and is equal to $\textrm{Spec}R$ for some $k$-algebra $R$, and we can then say the length is just the dimension of $R$ as a $k$-vector space).

What exactly does he mean by **scheme-theoretic multiplicity**?

(He later defines divisors associated to a projective subscheme $Z$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ on page 101 as $(Z)=\sum_i a_iP_i$, where $a_i$ are the scheme-theoretic multiplicities of $P_i\in Z$, i.e. "the length of the component of $Z$ at $P_i$," but I don't quite understand what this means either.)

Comment: The structure sheaf of a point is the stalk of the structure sheaf of $X$ at that point divided out by the maximal ideal defining the point. In particular it is a field. The degree of a point can then be defined as the degree of the structure sheaf over the base field $k$. Unless I'm mistaken that is what your writer means.

Comment: What is the degree of the structure sheaf? Is that just taking the dimension of the residue field of $P$ as a $k$-vector space? If so, it's not entirely to me why taking the sum of the degrees of points over all points in $X=\textrm{Spec}R$ is equal to the length, i.e. that $\dim_k R=\sum_{P\in X} \dim_k \kappa(P)$.

Comment: yes, I meant dimension over $k$. I may write a full answer later.